# Azure-Databricks media files (video) ingestion possible?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

Is it possible to bring video files that are on a storage container in Azure and ingest into Databricks DBFS in a way like you would ingest structured data files?

Specifically, is it possible to partition very large video files and ingest into Databricks?

Goal would be to ingest into DBFS or use the video on Azure from external storage to extract metadata and then go from there.

Comment: did you try anything ?

Comment: Ffmpeg does not seem to work unfortunately. I cannot use UDFs without outputting a python api error. Looking at a way if i can partition dbutils or run in parallel, but it seems this is also not a clear-cut option either. Trying though! Still wondering if anyone has any ideas. Its a bit time consuming when working with terabytes of media files :P